# Convert double* to float*

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I am wondering what how to convert `double*` to `float*`, and `float*` to `double*` in C or C++? Thanks. I tried cast using `(float*)` and `(double*)`, but it seems not working as far as my observation.

Comment: Converting the pointers does NOT convert the data pointed to. Converting float* to double* will NOT allow you to read the floats as (correct) double values.

Comment: State your actual problem. This cast is not the answer.

Comment: @NeilKirk I see. So how do I do it then?

Comment: Do what? Cast a float to a double? Conveniently convert an array of floats to an array of doubles? You need to ask a new question stating exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: You must pick a language because the solutions might be very different.

Comment: You can't convert the pointer types. Try assigning the data behind them: `*fp = *dp;`. (Of course if these point to arrays, then don't do this! Only do this if these are single values)

Comment: @adam10603 You can convert pointer types, it's just probably wrong in this case.

Comment: -1 for XY problem presented as an assumed solution with no evidence of research or of having learnt the language (_which one?_) or an actual problem to solve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Casting a pointer to a different type does not affect the values pointed to. Dereferencing such cast pointer will force reading or writing the contents of memory as a different type.  Since `double` and `float` have different incompatible representations, it causes undefined behaviour.

You can copy between `float` and `double` arrays using a simple loop, but you will actually be converting the values from one representation to the other, thereby losing precision when converting to `float` and not restoring it when you convert back to `double`.

Assuming dp and fp point to arrays with at least n elements:

```
void convert_float_to_double_array(double *dp, const float *fp, size_t n) {
    while (n--) *dp++ = *fp++;
}
```

Unless memory size is a real concern or you are programming for an embedded system with serious hardware limitations, you should not be using `float` at all.

Comment: Why not use the build-in copy function? `std::copy_n(fp, n, dp);`

Comment: @Potatoswatter: The question states both directions.

Comment: @Neil: There is no such language as C/C++.  More precisely, C/C++ invokes undefined behaviour ;-).  This answer is for C.  Any advanced compiler with optimize this correctly.  C++ may have other ways, that will not help the OP as the details are hidden and obscure.

Comment: @iharob: The comments already state why casting is inappropriate.  Should I paraphrase them?

Comment: Ok I didn't notice it is also tagged C. I'm not sure how a copy function can be "obscure" however.

Comment: @Neil: 1) `std::copy_n(fp, n, dp);` is inconsistent with `strcpy(dest, src)`.  2) Out of curiosity, I looked up std::copy_n and found this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n . The "possible implementation" is uselessly verbose, cumbersome and returns the wrong value.  The example is also a good illustration of "obscure".

Comment: 1. `copy_n` isn't anything to do with `strcpy` so I don't understand this point. Besides, you shouldn't call a function without knowing its parameters. 2. The possible implementation on that website is a bit strange. I don't understand why you think it returns the "wrong value" however. It returns what the standard says it does.

Comment: @chqrlie I see you already did it, and yes because often readers go directly to the answer and if it lacks such an important detail it's quality is compromised, very good answer BTW. And excelent C/C++ undefined behavior comment, once someone asked that here on SO.

Comment: @Neil: My bad, calling the destination `result` threw me off. regarding the inconsistency: `strcpy`, `memcpy` and many historical C library functions take the destination first and the source second, quite consistent with the assignement operator. `copy_n` does the opposite for no "obvious" reason.

Comment: I can see where you are coming from as a C background. The C++ functions tend to be input followed by output so that's just what I'm used to.

Comment: @Neil: Is there any plan to add slices in a future version of C++?  This would make the code more intuitive: `dp[0:n] = fp[0:n];`  or possibly: `dp[:n] = fp[*];`

Comment: Those who strongly desire such features emigrated long ago for languages new!

Comment: @chqrlie There has always been `std::slice`, and work is ongoing on generic ranges, but there's absolutely no hope for raw pointers, which civilized programmers abhor.